# Exception with a function

Tags: c++, exception

try, throw and catch works, however, cout << devide(a,b) << endl occurs an error.  How should I modify this code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


double devide(double a, double b) throw(int)
{
double result;
if (b == 0) throw 0;
result = a / b;
return result;
}



int main()
{
int a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
try {
    devide(a, b);
}
catch (int c) {
    cout << 100 << endl;
}
cout << devide(a,b) << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: *"occurs an error"* What does that mean? What is the error? Do you get a message? What does it say?

Comment: Also, you should not throw integers. Throw `std::invalid_argument` or something like that instead.

Comment: Do the output inside the try block.

Comment: Your post is very unclear about what the actual problem is. What is the error your getting? Is it a runtime or compile time error/ If it's a compile time error what's the exact message generated by the tool chain? information like this is important to helping you solve the problem.Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the section [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all throwing int is terrible idea, you should throw exception and there's [header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept) for it. You can write your own exceptions if you want but that doesn't matter right now.

Exceptions are for error handling don't use throws to "return different type" from functions and to do such barbaric things. You should throw only when there's no other way around.

In my example bellow I use [std::logic_error](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) because I think it suits the situation the best, since dividing by zero violates logical preconditions of any dividing function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

double divide(double a, double b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        // you cannot divide by zero so you are throwing exception 
        // to handle this edge case which has no mathematical solution
        throw logic_error("division by zero.");
    }
    return a / b;
}

int main() {
    int a = 0,
        b = 0;

    cin >> a >> b;

    try {
        // result of divide must be evaluated before calling on operator<< of cout
        // if it returns (b wasn't 0) it gets called and prints result into cout
        // if it throws an exception (b was 0) it gets handled in catch block
        cout << divide(a, b) << endl;
    } catch (const logic_error& err) {
        // printing error message
        cout << err.what() << endl; // prints "division by zero."
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is rather pointless to put the call inside a `try` when you later call it again outside of the `try`. You probably wanted something like this:

```
int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b;
    try {
        c = devide(a, b);
    }
    catch (exception e) {
        c = 100;
    }
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;


double devide(double a, double b) 
{
double result;
if (b == 0) throw 0;
result = a / b;
return result;
}



int main()
{
int a, b;


int res=10;



while(res>0){
try {
    cin >> a >> b;
        devide(a, b);
        res=-1;
    }
    catch (int c) {
        cout << 100 << endl;
    }
}

 }
```

Put all on a loop and change the condition only in positive case.